# Where is data stored in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not a react developer (I know basic js), however there is a web game (that runs on react) that I have been trying to look inside of and see if I can edit the stored values for a bit of fun. I checked the network tab and it seems to be all client based. I ran a js script to get all the objects, but all I could find was static data about the game, nothing storing my score or anything useful.

How is storage handled in react? How would I find/change data like my score?

Comment: Did you check the Redux? https://redux.js.org

Comment: If its client side it must be getting stored in the Async storage, considering its on android.

Comment: You can use the [React dev tools](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html) to view components' state, however you won't be able to edit state in this way in a production build of React.

Comment: I was able do edit the values by copying a state I found in the react dev tools into the console, but It only updated stuff like ui and didn't seem to change the actual game in any meaningful way. I assume that everything in js is some sort of object, is there really no way to change the values in a produced app?

Answer (score 7):

there are several places that we might store data in a react application;

- components states ( explore it via [react dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) )
- global states like Redux ([redux dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en)), Mobx or Contex API
- localStorage / sessionStorage ( explore it under `application` tab in inspector )
- cookies( used in server communication ), available via `document.cookie`
- local variables outside the components scope (kinda like global scope variables on javascript but not exactly); which is definitely not recommended but some people might do that. (the only way to explore them is by putting break points inside the `source` tab in the inspector; which is really hard to trace and investigate btw)

Comment: Thanks! really good answer